Self Consistency of Wave Function Given By Green Function ($\psi(r,t) = \psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt G_0(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi(r',t') $)
In "Introduction to Many-body Quantum theory in condensed matter physics" by Bruus and Flensberg there is an exercise regarding Green functions.
We want to solve the time dependent Schrödinger equation:
$[i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)]\psi(r,t) = 0$
using Green's function that are defined as
$[i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)]G(r,r',t,t') = \delta(r-r')\delta(t-t')$
Omitting the potential/perturbation gives us the $G_0$ Green's function.
It states that the following self-consistent expression solve the first equation:

$\psi(r,t) = \psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt G_0(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi(r',t') $
$\psi(r,t) = \psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt G(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi^0(r',t') $

I believe $\psi^0$ regards a particle wave function solving the non perturbated Schrödinger equation.
I want to verify as given in Ex. 7.1. that these are solutions.

$[i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)][\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' G(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi^0(r',t') ] \\= -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' [i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)]G(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi^0(r',t') \\= -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' \delta(r-r')\delta(t-t') V(r')\psi^0(r',t') = -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + V(r)\psi^0(r,t) = \mathbf{0 \quad \square} $

$[i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)][\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' G_0(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi(r',t')] \\= -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' [i\partial_t - H_0(r) - V(r)] G_0(r,r',t,t') V(r')\psi(r',t') \\= -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' [(\delta(r-r')\delta(t-t') - V(r)G_0(r,r',t,t')] V(r')\psi(r',t') \\= -V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + V(r)\psi(r,t) -\int dr'\int dt' [V(r)G_0(r,r',t,t')] V(r')\psi(r',t') = \quad (*)$


If I now assumme $(*)$ vanishes, I can arrange the equation to be
$ V(r)\psi(r,t) = V(r)\psi^0(r,t) + V(r) \int dr'\int dt' G_0(r,r',t,t')V(r')\psi(r',t') \\
\implies \mathbf{\psi(r,t) = \psi^0(r,t) + \int dr'\int dt' G_0(r,r',t,t')V(r')\psi(r',t')} $
This seems to be consistent, in the sense that if I assume that this $\psi$ satisfies the Schrödinger equation, it doesn't contradict itself.
Is this what I should show, or am I missing a step here?
It may be noted that I don't have a lecture and was reading about Green function for personal interest. So this is neither a homework nor is there anybody I could ask directyl, therefore I would be thankful if you can tell me if my calculation and observation was correct.
Thanks for your insights!
